# Force table's width (pandoc / default.latex)

Tags: tables, pandoc

Pandoc is working great at the moment, but I've got a problem for large tables. Most of the time the tables get rendered outside of the page. I know it has something to do with p|cm=8 or something, but I really have NO clue where to put it ;p.

My default.latex contains if(tables):

```
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable}
$endif$
```

Any chance to get some advice? :)

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I've already seen it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really too vague to answer but if you go

```
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{4cm}}
  aaaa & bbb\\
   ....
```

You will get a two column table, with the first column text being 3cm wide and the second column text being 4cm wide (with some default padding around the columns).

Comment: Im creating the tables out of a HTML source through Pandoc. Sometimes table's are to large for the page itself and the table is shown out of the page, so I'm not creating the table itself, but I want to configure it throughout the default.latex template of Pandoc.

Comment: @user2456177 that seems to be a pandoc question rather than a latex one so is probably off topic for this site, either way I haven't used pandoc so I can't help with that.